# How to compose several matrices into a big matrix diagonally in Pytorch

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, diagonal

I have several matrices, let's say `[M1,M2,M3,M4]`. Each matrix has a different shape. How do I compose these matrices into one big matrix diagonally like:

```
[[M1, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, M2, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, M2, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, M2]]
```

---

Example:

```
M1 = [[1,2],[2,1]]
M2 = [[1,2]]
M3 = [[3]]
M4 = [[3,4,5],[4,5,6]]
```

To compose this big matrix:

```
[[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it using SciPy:

```
from scipy.sparse import block_diag

block_diag((M1, M2, M3, M4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PyTorch's [`torch.block_diag()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.block_diag.html):

```py
>>> torch.block_diag(M1,M2,M3,M4)

tensor([[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6]])
```